# encoding/json unmarshal missing a field

Tags: json, go, serialization, tags, go-structtag

The following code unmarshal's the "Id", but not the "Hostname". Why? I've been staring at it for long enough now that if it's a typo I know I'll never spot it. Help please. (http://play.golang.org/p/DIRa2MvvAV)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type jsonStatus struct {
    Hostname string `json:host`
    Id       string `json:id`
}

func main() {
    msg := []byte(`{"host":"Host","id":"Identifier"}`)

    status := new(jsonStatus)

    err := json.Unmarshal(msg, &status)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unmarshall err", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Got status: %#v\n", status)
}
```

The output I get is

```
Got status: &main.jsonStatus{Hostname:"", Id:"Identifier"}
```

where I expect

```
Got status: &main.jsonStatus{Hostname:"Host", Id:"Identifier"}
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64598336/400544

Comment: I just got the same question closed because it's a typo: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64598336/400544

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your field tags are wrong. They need quotes around the alternate name.

```
type jsonStatus struct {
    //--------------------v----v
    Hostname string `json:"host"`
    Id       string `json:"id"`
}
```

Technically, you don't need a tag for the `Id` field at all. That's why that field was working.

***DEMO:*** http://play.golang.org/p/tiop27jNJe

Comment: Doh, I can't believe I missed that. I also didn't realize that the key names aren't case sensitive when unmarshal'ing. Thank you!